# Is [ComImport] considered P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke

What ***is*** Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)?

---

What does it mean to be performing a P/Invoke? Is it [calling an external dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)? e.g.:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
      int hwndOwner, 
      string lpszPath,
      ceFolders nFolder,
      bool fCreate);
```

Is that what P/Invoke means: to use the `[DllImport]` attribute?

Is there anything else that can be considered a `P/Invoke`?

What about `[ComImport]`? e.g.:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComImport]
[Guid("F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4")]
public class ProgressDialog
{
}
```

**Note**: This COM class (F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4) can be found in

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4}
      (default)       %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
      ThreadingModel  Both
```

i could also construct a native `ADO Recordset` object with the code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComImport]
[Guid("00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4")]
public class Recordset
{
}

Object rs= new Recordset();
```

Is that considered P/Invoke?

If we choose to say "P/Invoke is bad", is ComImport as "bad" as DllImport?

What ***is*** Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)?

---

**Update**: From MSDN:

> ### [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
>
> Platform Invocation Services (PInvoke) allows managed code to call
>   unmanaged functions that are implemented in a DLL.
>
> There are two ways that C# code can directly call unmanaged code:
>
> - Directly call a function exported from a DLL.
> - Call an interface method on a COM object (for more information, see C[OM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

i think i may have answered my own question.

---

It's a year and a half later. Now that nobody is paying attention to the question, and nobody has it favorited, i can say that the answer i accepted is wrong. `P/Invoke` is short for `Platform Invoke`. It is a mechanism where managed code operating inside the CLR can call unmanaged native (i.e. platform) code. This is nearly always done by calling code that resides in a native dll. COM dlls *are* native code; they just follow a strict structure to allow many different compilers to call them.

And Platform Invoke is bad. It bypasses all garbage collection, and depends on the platform (i.e. my 32-bit CLR process cannot load a 64-bit dll, my application written for Android cannot work on Windows, my application written for functionality on Windows 8 won't work on Windows XP).

Comment: "P/Invoke is bad" this statement is false.  It can be bad, depends on several factors, just like anything can be bad.  Anyone that makes that sort of general statement only shows their inexperience.  It also shows the lack of understand how the .NET Framework even works.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for not understanding what i was saying.

Comment: Be careful how you enterpret that section you just pasted in your update! Note how it mentions two ways to call unmanaged code from C#, but it doesn't say they're both P/Invoke. In fact, COM is mentioned *nowhere else* in that article. The other text strongly suggests P/Invoke only applies to the first of those two points. Indeed, observe that there is a separate *COM Interop Tutorials* page on MSDN (see the navigation bar), which is made distinct from Platform Invoke.

Comment: P/invoke is certainly not bad per se. Used instead of perfectly good managed alternatives, then yes. Used as a way to reach libraries that would otherwise be unreachable, for which there are no managed alternatives, it is very good. For instance, my product is an unmanaged program that exposes an API via an unmanaged DLL. How else would you propose a .net consumer to gain access to it. There's no managed alternative.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's when you create the platform independent managed alternative. How would I run your app on a non-Intel device?

Comment: @IanBoyd You cannot. It only exists on Windows.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But not Windows RT? What about Windows CE? Windows Phone?

Comment: @IanBoyd What of them? Can you expand your point. Remember that you are trying to build an argument that interop between managed and unmanaged is bad.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it much matters whether it is pinvoke or not. That's just naming. What matters and what exercised you is whether or not pinvoke is in some sense worse then comimport, by some definition of worse. I cannot really tell the difference between them to be honest.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i see the confusion now. i wasn't trying to claim that `DllImport` was *"bad"* and `ComImport` is *"good"*. i was asking if `ComImport` has the same downsides as `DllImport`. More specifically, when using the term `Platform Invoke`, does that also include `ComImport`. i realized the answer is "Yes". If you call native code, you are doing a *"Platform Invoke"*. And with a platform invoke comes all the problems. In your case the problem is lack of portability to other Windows operating systems. But there are also issues of garbage collection, security, type safety.

Comment: Calling a native DLL with `DllImport` is morally equivalent to calling a COM object. Everything that can go wrong with one can go wrong with the other. In my case, I have no problems at all. The fact that my code only runs on desktop Windows is not a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not the same. [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (platform invoke) always involves calling native DLLs directly using the CLR functionality. "Native DLLs" means any DLL that expoes `extern "C"` functions. Managed DLLs don't let you expose them; such a DLL is typically written in C/C++. The give-away signature of P/Invoke in managed code is a `DllImport` attribute (or `extern` function in C#). Reading the P/Invoke page gives no mention of COM anywhere.

Using [`ComImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comimportattribute.aspx) is for the purpose of creating a custom interop assembly (i.e. something hand-crafted rather than a PIA automatically generated by `TlbImp`), and uses inherent CLR functionality that is quite independent from the P/Invoke functionality, and specific to COM.

The similarities lie in that both these methods are used for interoperating with *unmanaged code*. Support for both is baked into the CLR, and although in theory one could use the Windows API to do COM interop completely manually in managed code, it makes no sense when .NET provides a structure means for you, in terms of primary or custom interop assemblies as well as lower-level support in `System.ComponentModel`.

Comment: i'm not using `ComImport` with a custom interop assembly. i am constructing a native com class in `shell32.dll`. Is calling native code in a native dll's *not* P/Invoke?

Comment: @rekire: No problem. It's an easy point to confuse anyway, as there are certainly similarities.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Constructing a native com class? What do you mean by that? `ComImport` is only relevant to already-defined COM types.

Comment: And no, in any case, you're not the one doing the P/Invoke. The .NET Framework may be doing one *internally* on the relevant Win32 DLL (I forget which one it is), but you yourself are certianly not "p/invoking".

Comment: It seems to turn into splitting hairs. With `[DllImport]` i'm not using a native dll. The runtime is calling `LoadLibrary` and then `GetProcAddress(SHGetSpecialFolderPath)` then the function `SHGetSpecialFolderPath(...)`. With `[ComImport]` the runtime is calling `LoadLibrary`, and then `GetProcAddress(DllGetClassObject)` and then the function `DllGetClassObject(...)`.

Comment: @IanBoyd: It's not. P/Inboke specifically refers to doing native function calls from within managed code. I'm not sure if the COM functionality resides in the CLR (runtime itself) or the BCL (.NET lirbaries). If it's the former, then one cannot say a P/Invoke is being done anywhere! If it's the latter, then it's hidden from you. You're muddling up the concept of P/Invokes and unmanaged calls. There's no doubt in any case that `DllImport` is P/Invoking, where as `[ComImport]` is certianly not.

Comment: Native DLLs can export functions without extern "C" and these can be called from pinvoke. A native DLL is, well, a native DLL.